# exif_imagetype(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C on line 30

Tags: php, image, upload

Okay so, I try to upload a photo into a folder. It works when uploading only one photo, but when I try to upload a second photo it doesn't allow me to and returns this error:

```
Warning: exif_imagetype(gallery/inerieur abu 3.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\campi\admin\upload-gallery.php on line 30

Warning: unlink(gallery/inerieur abu 3.jpg): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\campi\admin\upload-gallery.php on line 34
```

This is my code, I use a function to check the image and upload it into the folder

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
if (isset($_POST['gallery-upload'])) {
    $hostname='localhost';
    $username='root';
    $password='';
    $filter = $_POST['filter'];

    function uploadImage($img_ff, $dst_path, $dst_img){

        //Get variables for the function.
                //complete path of the destination image.
        $dst_cpl = $dst_path . basename($dst_img);
                //name without extension of the destination image.
        $dst_name = preg_replace('/\.[^.]*$/', '', $dst_img);
                //extension of the destination image without a "." (dot).
        $dst_ext = strtolower(end(explode(".", $dst_img)));

    //Check if destination image already exists, if so, the image will get an extra number added.
        while(file_exists($dst_cpl) == true){
            $i = $i+1;
            $dst_img = $dst_name . $i . '.' . $dst_ext;
            $dst_cpl = $dst_path . basename($dst_img);
        }

            //upload the file and move it to the specified folder.
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$img_ff]['tmp_name'], $dst_cpl);

            //get type of image.
        $dst_type = exif_imagetype($dst_cpl);

            //Checking extension and imagetype of the destination image and delete if it is wrong.
        if(( (($dst_ext =="jpg") && ($dst_type =="2")) || (($dst_ext =="jpeg") && ($dst_type =="2")) || (($dst_ext =="gif") && ($dst_type =="1")) || (($dst_ext =="png") && ($dst_type =="3") )) == false){
            unlink($dst_cpl);
            die('<p>The file "'. $dst_img . '" with the extension "' . $dst_ext . '" and the imagetype "' . $dst_type . '" is not a valid image. Please upload an image with the extension JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF and has a valid image filetype.</p>');
        }
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

            //Variables needed for the function.
        $img_ff = 'image'; // Form name of the image
        $dst_img = strtolower($_FILES[$img_ff]['name']); // This name will be given to the image. (in this case: lowercased original image name uploaded by user).
        $dst_path = 'gallery/'; // The path where the image will be moved to.

        uploadImage($img_ff, $dst_path, $dst_img);
            try {

                $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dddoecje_campu",$username,$password);
                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `gallery`(`id`, `image`, `filter`) VALUES ('',:image,:filter)");
                $stmt->bindParam(':filter', $filter);
                $stmt->bindParam(':image', $dst_img, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                $dbh->errorInfo();
                $stmt->execute();
                // use exec() because no results are returned
                header("Location: index.php?lang=" . $lang);

            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $stmt . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }
    }



    $dbh = null;
}
?>
```

After that the image should be uploaded it sets the name in the database, that works but it doesn't get uploaded into the destination folder.
I've tried everything that comes to mind for me but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As per [PHP - file upload, exif_imagetype() warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437536/php-file-upload-exif-imagetype-warning) `exif_imagetype()` needs to be run against the `temp` file name, not the file name.

As in `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` not `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`

As is what's happening in your code.

Add near:

> $dst_img = strtolower($_FILES[$img_ff]['name']);
>
> `$dst_tmp_img = strtolower($_FILES[$img_ff]['tmp_name']);`

And change function to:

> function uploadImage($img_ff, $dst_path, $dst_img`, $dst_tmp_img`)

Then change `$dst_type` value to equal:

> $dst_type = exif_imagetype(`$dst_tmp_img`);

Then you're code will work more reliably.